# How to keep query persistent throughout the website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I have a rails app and when a user opens my website, if they came from the link in the email, I put `?email=true` in the url. If there is a query in the url, I show a different navbar.

However, as soon as the user clicks on some other link in the website, the query disappears and the old navbar is shown.

How can I keep the query there at all times if they came from the email?

Comment: use browser's local storage

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use javascript and save the flag in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

```
const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
const url = new URL(location.href);
const fromMail = !!url.searchParams.get('email') || !!localStorage.getItem('fromMail');

if (fromMail) {
  localStorage.setItem('fromMail', '1');
  navbar.classList.add('email-navbar');
} else {
  navbar.classList.add('default-navbar');
}
```

Comment: OP don't want to just change class name.

Comment: @Vishal then would you tell me how to show different navbar? IF statement of template language such as HAML or SLIM?

Comment: set partial view of different navbars, show conditional partials

Comment: do you mean the way like this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967324/slim-langs-if-else-nested-code/

Comment: No, i don't mean that